# apache2 slow responding (debian)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, apache-2.2, mod-python

I'm running an apache2 2.2.9 webserver with modpython and mpm_worker_module.

The current config for the mpm is

```
ServerLimit 32
StartServers         10
MaxClients          800
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
```

The server has 1G of ram and a 100Mbit connection.

Checking *netstat -na | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l* gives me a number between 50 - 60.
The load is about 1.0
Every pageload is also cached by memcached.

I can't see why the server is so slow in responding to new connections, sometimes droping them completely?

Also tried disabling iptables to make sure it's not because of a full state table or something like that.

The only thing in dmesg is a lot of spam about "TCP: Treason uncloaked!"

Even connections to localhost with apache2ctl status fails, so it shouldn't be modpython related.
When the status do work, it shows around 110-128 requests being processed.
About half are status C (closing connection), lots of _ (Waiting for connection), the rest being R and W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the error_log report? It's the best place to start debugging these kind of problems.

top is also a good way to debug this. Run top and check if the Apache processes are using too much CPU. Then type M to sort the processes by memory usage and check if they're consuming too much RAM.

Check also if you are swapping:

```
free
```

The memcached runs on the same server? If so, how much memory does it have allocated?

Also, are you having trouble with i/o wait? Check the %wa value when running top.

Regarding the network, are you having errors or CRCs? Check it with netstat:

```
netstat -i
```

Take a look the RX-ERR, RX-DRP, TX-ERR and TX-DRP columns. Ideally, these values should be 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the list, here is the output:

The CPU is mostly about 75% idle.
Each apache (about 7 in the list) consume about 3-8% cpu.
Each apache has 39M (RES) and 310M (VIRT).
%wa maxes out on 7%, most of the time it's 0%.
Zero errors on netstat.
Memcached is on the same server and has 165M.

The only error in the apache log is from modpython that complains about "IOError: Write failed, client closed connection."

Comment: And I do have 284M used on swap

Comment: Even connections to localhost (apache2ctl status) fails to establish at times (after waiting several minutes)

Comment: Also make sure you look at your application.  You said you're using the threaded MPM; I don't suppose there are any situations where you may be blocking on hot locks?   Check the output of `free`, what does it list for available memory? What about after +/- buffers?

Comment: I'm not sure about the "hot locks"? This is a python django application.
Mem:       1034680    1021432      13248          0       9420     455428.
-/+ buffers/cache:     556584     478096

Comment: So, yeah, the RAM is a bit on the low side, but I wouldn't think that would cause a situation like you're seeing. My guess is that the slowness is caused by the application.  A slow DB query, a DB connection delay, a threading.Lock mutex that multiple threads are waiting on... something like that.